# Use HTML email template in Outlook, without Outlook messing up the HTML?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

I know how to create an HTML email template for Outlook, by copying your HTML file (in Windows) to %AppData%\Microsoft\Stationery. However, if you use the template to send emails Outlook messes around with it first - adding CSS to the head, stripping out things like media queries (from the head), adding its own CSS classes to the HTML etc etc.

Is there a way this can be avoided or minimised?

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ it explains which mailbox supports what.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think you read my question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook completely rewrites the HTML using the MS Word rendering engine when you send out. Pretty much once Outlook has its claws on your email, it is now a Word doc.

Also, I would recommend saving the code as an HTML file, then using Insert > Document >Insert as Text option when you go to send a new email in Outlook to create your HTML email instead of stationary.  This allows much more leniency in HTML/CSS display. ([Walkthrough](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/26))

Designing for sending from Outlook is extremely tricky and unless you have an experienced HTML/CSS email designer, I would recommend (as much as it pains me to say) that you just create it through Word and saving as HTML file. As long as it is going from Outlook to Outlook, there should be little to no discrepancy in design.

If you are going to send to recipients that do not use Outlook, then you will need another email client to send from or deal with the fact that either these people will get less than optimal email messages or create a super simple design that can display well across all email clients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that is essentially the conclusion we had come to!